# How to make fallback for images correctly?

Tags: nginx

I have the following location that handles my assets:

```
location ~ \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|png) {
  root /var/static;
}
```

So if a request is

```
www.mysite.com/img/file.png
```

the file.png will be taken from

```
/var/static/css/file.png
```

That's correct. But in some cases I need to handle the following request:

```
 www.mysite.com/css/file1.png
```

And take it from the img directory

```
 /var/static/img/file1.png
```

How should I change my location?

Comment: Are you sure about the examples you gave? I can't see, how a reqeust to `www.mysite.com/img/file.png` would go to `/var/static/css/file.png`. I'd say it's rather `/var/static/img/file.png`.

Comment: reqeust to www.mysite.com/css/file.png would go to /var/static/img/file.png It's bad I know but I need  
quick workaround now.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. A request to `.../img/...` can not go to `.../css/...` with your configuration. You claimed that in your first example.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
# images that start with css
location ~ ^css(?:/[^/])*(?<filename>/[^/]*\.(?:jpe?g|png)) {
    root /var/static;
    try_files css/$filename img/$filename;
}

#normal images
location ~ (?<filename>[^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|png)) {
    root /var/static;
    try_files $filename $filename/;
}

#put separate rules for js and css
```

Comment: Thanks this works. How can I rewrite all pathes like www.mysite.com/assets/folder/file.png for getting from /var/static/img ?

Comment: you want to map between `assets` and `/var/static` ?

Comment: My problem is I have request's assets like: /assets/sub/file.png , /assets/file.png /css/file.png and all of them I need map tp /var/static/img

Comment: you want to ignore the `/sub` ?

Comment: could there be several subs? or just 1 ?

Comment: I may have any nesting. I need to get only filename

Comment: try the edited answer, not sure if it would even work or not, but worth trying